# Shell Script to generate word list with non repeating characters

Tags: shell, lisp, words

I found a lisp program. It works, but not exactly how I need it too. It outputs like this:

```
2323232323235ve3
2323232323235ve4
2323232323235ve5
2323232323235ve6
```

I need to make a word list, with words that are 16 characters long using Base32 characters, with non repeating characters in the word.
Then I need to add `.txt` to the word.

```
asdfjklwert7csui.txt
jcfklinesftw8se3.txt
```

Then I need to SHA512 the word and check against a known hash.

**Would it be possible just to output the word that matches the known hash?**

Here is the LISP source

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/clisp

(defparameter *character-set* "234567abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
;(defparameter *character-set* "ABC")     ; < --- this line is for testing

(defparameter *word-length* 16)
;(defparameter *word-length* 4)           ; < --- this line is for testing

(defparameter *character-list*
       (coerce *character-set* 'list))

(defun final-char (in-string)
   (cond
      ((> (length in-string) 0)
         (elt in-string (1- (length in-string))))
      (t
         nil)))

(defun new-char-list (in-string)
   (let ((result))
      (mapcar
         (lambda (candidate)
            (cond
               ((not (eql candidate (final-char in-string)))
                  (push candidate result))))
         *character-list*)
      (nreverse result))
      )

(defun extend-string (in-string desired-length)
   (mapcar
      (lambda (new-char)
         (let ((new-string (concatenate 'string in-string (string new-char))))
            (cond
               ((>  (length new-string) desired-length))
               ((>= (length new-string) desired-length)
                  (format t "~a~%" new-string))
               (t
                  (extend-string new-string desired-length)))))
      (new-char-list in-string)))

(extend-string "" *word-length*)
```

Bash Script outputs to file and looks like. I need output to be lower case.

```
K5SMKLK5W85T6GTC
RZJRNV0VO1LVIMEM
RPSW59OPQLUBJKC5
```

Here is Bash Script

```
#!/bin/bash
ascii=
index=0
noNames=16                                              #No of names to generate
nameLength=10                                           #Length to generate (you said 10)
for(( i=65; i<=90; i++ ))                               #Add upper-case letters to 'ascii'
do
        ascii[$index]=$(echo $i | awk '{printf("%c",$1)}')
        index=$(( $index + 1 ))
done

for(( i=48; i<=57; i++ )) # Add numbers to 'ascii'
do
        ascii[$index]=$(echo $i | awk '{printf("%c",$1)}')
        index=$(( $index + 1))
done

for(( i=0; i<$noNames; i++))
do
    name=                                           #We'll store the name in here
    last=                                           #We'll store the index of the last 
                                                        #   character generated here
    for(( j=0; j<$nameLength; j++))
    do  
        num=$(( $RANDOM % $index ))             # Pick a random character index
        while [[ $num -eq $last ]]              #If it's the same as the last 
                                                        #  one...
        do
            num=$(( $RANDOM % $index ))     #... pick a new one!
        done
        last=$num                               #Update "last" to current value
            name=${name}${ascii[$num]}              #Add the correct letter to our name
    done
    echo "${name}"                                  #Print name...
done > output                                           #...to our output file
```

Comment: I don't know the standard lisp library, but if possible, I would first generate the whole alphabet, like your character set. Then shuffle it, and cut out the first 16 characters. Need more? Shuffle and cut again. I don't understand the part with the hash.

Comment: This was something I found from an old post on https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/generate-special-alphanumeric-wordlist-no-repeating-characters-side-by-side-862473/

I don't know lisp but out of the solutions it was the fastest.

Comment: There are 601,080,390 possible combinations, with 32 choose 16, according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=32+choose+16).  I don't think anything written in Shell is going to do that quickly, especially if you have to calculate an SHA512 sum too.  Also, LISP isn't Shell.

Comment: @BenStern
Riight, I didn't know what LISP was when I asked the question.  2nd oldest program language.

Comment: Ah, I guess I misunderstood the specification. "non repeating characters in the word" doesn't mean distinct characters, but no pairs of the same character, like '2323' is allowed, '2332' forbidden. Then the alphabet shuffling is of course nonsense. -- In the shell, `time echo -e {1..10500}"\n" | parallel 'a={}; echo $a | sha512sum' | wc -l  produces 10500 values and hashes them in parallel, 2x2core CPU, 5y'o, takes about 50s. No comparing of result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Common Lisp answer, tested with SBCL.
Since you need to compute a hash, I am going to use an external library named [Ironclad](http://method-combination.net/lisp/ironclad/). In order to install it, first 
[Install Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/screencast.gif). Then:

```
(ql:quickload :ironclad)
```

This part can be customized:

```
(defparameter *character-set* "234567abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
(defparameter *suffix* ".txt")
```

### Auxiliary functions

Now, we are going to map over all possible strings which respect your constraints (no same consecutive characters). And we are also going to manipulate those strings as bytes, because Ironclad only computes hash from vectors of bytes. There is no need to allocate so many strings, just reuse the same buffer over and over:

```
(defun make-buffer (size)
  (concatenate '(vector (unsigned-byte 8))
               (make-array size :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
               (ironclad:ascii-string-to-byte-array *suffix*)))
```

The above allocates the required vector of bytes, taking into account the suffix, converted as bytes.
Below, we will do the same with the character set, which is also coerced as a list (to be able to use [`DOLIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm)):

```
(defun make-character-set ()
  (coerce (ironclad:ascii-string-to-byte-array *character-set*)
          'list))
```

We also want to be able to convert a hash string into a vector of bytes, but also accept vectors directly. The following function ensures the given value is converted as the desired type:

```
(defun ensure-hash (hash-designator)
  (etypecase hash-designator
    (string (ironclad:hex-string-to-byte-array hash-designator))
    (vector (coerce hash-designator '(vector (unsigned-byte 8))))))
```

### Find hash

Now, we can find a hash given a set of generated words. The `SIZE` argument indicates how many characters are present before the suffix, and `HASH-DESIGNATOR` is a string in hexadecimal notation, or a vector of bytes:

```
(defun find-hash (size hash-designator)
  (let ((hash (ensure-hash hash-designator))
        (buffer (make-buffer size))
        (character-set (make-character-set)))
    (labels ((level (depth forbidden)
               (cond
                 ((>= depth size)
                  (when (equalp hash (ironclad:digest-sequence
                                      'ironclad:sha512 buffer))
                    (return-from find-hash
                      (values (map 'string #'code-char buffer)
                              buffer))))
                 (t (let ((next (1+ depth)))
                      (dolist (c character-set)
                        (unless (= c forbidden)
                          (setf (aref buffer depth) c)
                          (level next c))))))))
      (level 0 0))))
```

The general case of the local `level` function consists in setting the character at position `depth` in buffer, according to the character set, and ignoring the forbidden character, which is the last one being set (or initially, zero). When `level` reaches `size`, we have our word stored in buffer as a vector of bytes. In that case, we hash that word and compare it with the desired hash. If there is a match, we convert the array of bytes (character codes) as a string, and also return the internal buffer (it is already computed, maybe it can be reused).

### Example

```
(find-hash 3 "ddd2379f9a1adf4f0afa0befafdb070fb942d4d4e0331a31d43494149307221e5e699da2a08f59144b0ed415dea6f920cf3dab8ca0b740d874564d83b9b6f815")
=> "zyc.txt"
   #(122 121 99 46 116 120 116)
```

The task is however going to be impractical for 16 characters, due to the exponential complexity:

```
> (time (find-hash 4 #(0)))
Evaluation took:
  1.679 seconds of real time
  1.676000 seconds of total run time (1.672000 user, 0.004000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.028 seconds GC time, and 1.648 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.82% CPU
  4,019,832,288 processor cycles
  899,920,096 bytes consed

NIL

> (time (find-hash 5 #(0)))
Evaluation took:
  51.768 seconds of real time
  51.796000 seconds of total run time (51.684000 user, 0.112000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.952 seconds GC time, and 50.844 seconds non-GC time. ]
  100.05% CPU
  123,956,130,558 processor cycles
  27,897,672,624 bytes consed
```

Comment: I've tested this, but not getting any output.  If I run a 3 char test, runs in a second but no output. Possibly fact that I changed suffix.  Is there a limit on suffix length?

Comment: @Jcfunk Updated code and tests with sha512 digest. There should not be a limit on suffix length, do you have more details?

Comment: I'm having issues with my hash.  For some reason sha512sum is giving the wrong hash.  My hash for zyc.txt is 
echo "zyc.txt" | sha512sum 
11aa472bf4c97ffb1fae06a3f7175127da084c5dfb840038ee308b37136330e5b6a56cc053c62881f10aec88948d8addb1d4844496cdb08e4067b4fd4601330e

Comment: @Jcfunk After some tests, it appears that echo introduces a newline character. If you do `echo -n "zyc.txt" | sha512sum`, you should have the hash that starts with `ddd2379`. You can also add a newline in the suffix.